# Swift Could not import Obj-C Module?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, oauth

I'm making an app, and I downloaded the framework for OAuthSwift off Github, [here](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift) and I did all the steps except the last one under installation. It did not work when I tried to do the last step, `import OAuthSwift` and gave me an error saying `Could not build Obj-C Module 'OAuthSwift'`. What does this mean? OAuthSwift, as the name, is in swift, and why can't I get it to work?

Comment: You need to list the exact steps you did. There's not much here to work from.

Comment: What else is there to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Build Settings under the heading "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" have you got a "Objective-C Bridging Header"? 
If so is it set to your bridging header file? If it isn't you can do this by double clicking on the file path name and drag in your bridging header file from the left into the box that pops up

Comment: What bridging header file? Do I need one?

Comment: Ye that's probably the problem then, create a new file and select header file, name it what you want with the target being your project. then follow what I said above about dragging the file into your swift compiler - code generation under build settings. You should be good to import your obj-c modules there

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with Obj-C, what things would I need to import there? Would I need to do an import for the OAuthSwift?

Comment: I found a file in the project for the framework that is a header file, what should I put there, if anything?

Comment: In that file what is there? like is there anything like "import some file.h" or something?

Comment: or take some screen shots for me I can't quite understand what you have. If its a framework you should just be able to add it into your Build Phases and it should just work. (you know if its a farm work it will say "something.framework" or if its just a obj-c file it will be something.h or something.m"

Comment: This is the code:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for OAuthSwift.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double OAuthSwiftVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for OAuthSwift.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char OAuthSwiftVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <OAuthSwift/PublicHeader.h>

Comment: I don't think this is the thing though

Comment: It says in the github thing that you can just import it using 'import OAuthSwift' in your Swift files

Comment: There were a few errors in the code for the framework, a few incorrect syntaxes and such. I fixed them and now it's working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey no worries glad you got there in the end, it's always silly little things hey. Best of luck, Dom